# Is there a document describing cstyle rules?

Tags: c, coding-style

I can read through the cstyle script and deduce what it will complain about, but I was hoping to find a clear concise document spelling out the rules of cstyle in English.

For example, cstyle.pl can be found here:
http://cvs.opensolaris.org/source/xref/onnv/onnv-gate/usr/src/tools/scripts/cstyle.pl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [community page](http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Community+Group+on/) for the ONNV project that script was hosted at, I found this Cstyle guide.

http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/download/Community+Group+on/WebHome/cstyle.ms.pdf

Comment: I was hoping for something shorter than 31 pages, but I believe you found the perfect answer. Thanks.

Comment: That site seems to have gone offline. I see one on sourceforge that appears online right now: http://sourceforge.net/projects/schilytools/files/cstyle/cstyle.ms.pdf/download